Скачать видео с YouTube. Обойти защиту капчи
Мне нужно скачать видео с юпупа.Взять из него аудиодорожку и перевести в текст
Мой код для скачивания:
# Функция для загрузки видео с YouTube и извлечения аудиодорожки
def download_audio_from_youtube(url):

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'm4a/bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'm4a',
        }],
        'outtmpl': 'downloads/youtube.m4a',
    }

    try:
        with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            error_code = ydl.download([url])
            if error_code == 0:
                logger.info(f'Аудиофайл успешно загружен: youtube.m4a')
                return 'downloads/youtube.m4a'
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f'Ошибка во время загрузки аудио: {str(e)}')
        return None

Ошибка следующая:
ERROR - Ошибка во время загрузки аудио: Sign in to confirm you’re not a bot. This helps protect our community. Learn more

Какие есть идеи как это обойти? Пробовала несколько вариантов с стороними сервисами, не днадежные

Использовать прокси/впн, смену UA

Если не сложно поделиться гайдами, буду рада. В приоритете бесплатные.

Так же интересно, как будет работать код, если он будет отрабатывать на иностранном сервере. Как понимаю эту проблему не нужно будет решать? Может стоит сначала запустить код на тестовом сервере, до пробы костылей?
